# Which digit am I thinking of?

Tags: number-sequence

Find a 10-digit number where the first digit is how many zeros in the number, the second digit is how many 1s in the number etc. until the tenth digit which is how many 9s in the number.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

> 6210001000

Comment: How did you get that number?